# How can I make my navigation bar disappear under a drop-down button when I shrink my website?

Tags: hide, shrink

When I shrink my web, the web doesn’t auto resize, and my na bar is in a messy situation. so I thought that maybe by hiding the na bar when my website shrinks would solve the problem .

N/A: nothing. In fact, I do not know which function would help me with this Matter.